# Is there a difference between these words for “hero”?

Tags: usage, words, definitions, word-choice

I've learned that hero could be translated as:

- ヒーロー
- えいゆう
- ゆうしゃ
- けっし

Aside from ヒーロー (which seems just to be roumaji version of hero), is there any usage difference among them?

Comment: けえし does not look like a Japanese word (it is rare to have え after an -e letter), and it is probably a typo for something ([剣士]{けんし}?).

Comment: Does ヒーロー get used for heroines (female heroes)?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto You're right. It was けっし.

Comment: There is a Japanese word けっし (決死), but it does not refer to a person at all….

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto 傑士 I believe is the kanji for it.

Comment: @dotnetN00b The word 傑士 is rare enough that neither TsuyoshiIto nor I could come up with in mind.

Comment: Aha!  As sawa said, I could not come up with it, but I agree that 傑士 is a valid word.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm This jpop singer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tuv033I0wRI says [ヒーローイン] which by the video seems to be in reference to a female.

Comment: @taylor Well isn't `ヒーローイン` just roumaji for heroine? In which case, it would make perfect sense.

Comment: We normally spell it as ヒロイン.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: I think you are confused about the meaning of the word 'romaji' (what you are thinking here is 'katakana').

Comment: @Dave lol. you're right. `ヒーローイン` I see that in katakana and think romanization. Although I know there's a term for writing/pronouncing words as close to the foreign/original way as possible.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The singer is not saying ヒーローイン nor does the roman transcription say so. It is ヒロイン, as Chocolate mentions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

英雄 is most normally used for heros whose status as such is established. ヒーロー implies an American hero. For example, Beethoven's third symphony is called 英雄 in Japanese, but no one would call it ヒーロー. 勇者 means someone who is brave, and is not the same as hero. 傑士 is not normally used.

Japanese hero shows are called [戦隊もの](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E6%88%A6%E9%9A%8A%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA), as it comes from the early hero shows like 秘密戦隊ゴレンジャー, 電子戦隊デンジマン, 太陽戦隊サンバルカン.

Comment: 勇者{ゆうしゃ} is never used to mean hero?

Comment: @dotnetN00b It can be used as long as that hero is brave as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about this old question recently. 勇者 as 'hero' may seem confusing to people who aren't big into pop culture, but in fantasy, especially fantasy video games (I think Dragon Quest may have originated this), 勇者 can refer to a 'chosen one'. This is a very particular use though and not exactly mainstream.

Comment: I suppose that a hero in a typical RPG is more like a [classical Western](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero%27s_journey) conception, which is different from either an American comic-book superhero (or the American folk heroes that inspired that variety of storytelling) or one of the good guys in a tokusatsu. (I say "Western", but maybe there is a segment of Japanese folklore that I'm unaware of which fits the mold.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a combination with two of them using one as an ateji of another:

[label](https://sites.google.com/site/freedomorita/suppaman/orita0510.jpg)
[statue](https://sites.google.com/site/freedomorita/suppaman/orita0505.jpg)

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Mainly, because I thought you accidentally posted in the thread.

Comment: This is just a joke, as well as telling in an ironically way that you cannot always differentiate different words. One may not be able to read the message if they are not smart enough. I do not care if someone downvotes, but I can guess that whomever did it probably cannot even read the kanji in 英雄.

Comment: @sawa I thought you guys with all that rep get special moderator tools that let you look under the hood to see things like who downvoted.

Comment: @Louis: Votes are anonymous.

Comment: @Louis I thought so too before I got high reps, but it is only available to the moderators.

Comment: Ah, I often see the ateji combination of "[英雄]{ヒーロー}" (though I've never seen "[ヒーロー]{えいゆう}" or "[ヒーロー]{英雄}". ^o^)